# Concatenate value in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want it to click in a hidden button on the tabs, I'm trying to concatenate the name of the Previous tab with the string btn, when I debug in Firefox I have these values

```
var previous_Tab = $(e.relatedTarget).attr("href");
```

previous_Tab = General

`var btnClick = "#btn" + tabs[strNum];`

btnClick give the value = btnUndefined

it should be btnGeneral

This is my code :

```
      $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var sitePath = $this.attr('href');
            var previous_Tab = $(e.relatedTarget).attr("href");
            var Actived_Tab = $(e.target).attr("href");

            var Previous_tab_Index = $(e.relatedTarget).parent().index();
            var Next_tab_Index = $(e.target).parent().index();

            var btnClick = "#btn" + tabs[previous_Tab];
            // call the trigger the hidden btn in each form to do the post
            $(btnClick).trigger('click');
        })
```

Comment: Since you've edited it, `tabs` is still not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't be the below?

```
var btnClick = "#btn" + previous_Tab;
```

Comment: This question makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks I find out after that I post that I put Tabs before the name of my var, I know this question make no sense, sorry for that